# ImportError: cannot import name '_deprecate_positional_args' from 'sklearn.utils.validation'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

when I try to import deprecate_positional_args fuction from sklearn.utils.validation' I got this import error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_deprecate_positional_args' from 'sklearn.utils.validation'
```

The scikit-learn version is 0.21.3

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same error when running in a Jupyter environment. Was resolved by installing `imbalanced-learn` by running `!pip install -U imbalanced-learn` and then restarting the runtime. Restarting the runtime is the key here. If you don't restart, the error won't go.

Comment: restarting is indeed what I was missing when trying to fix this problem. Thank you.

Comment: no other install required - just restart!! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by upgrading *scikit-learn*:

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a mismatch between the scikit-learn versions with which you train the model and load the model. Check your scikit-learn versions with `sklearn.__version__` and up/downgrade one of the packages with `pip install --upgrade scikit-learn==<version_number>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that some of the answers here will work provided that you're working with Python 3.7 or a newer version. I couldn't upgrade to a newer Python version due to workplace restrictions and what worked for me was downgrading to scikit-learn 0.23.

You can do it via the command

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.23
```

Or, if you're using Jupyter Notebook:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install scikit-learn==0.23
```